# Cannot remove a certificate from Windows Azure Website "Updating configuration failed"

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service

1. Open Windows Azure Portal > Click Web Sites > Choose MyWebsite
2. Click Configure > Scroll to Certificates > Remove a Certificate > Save

> Updating the configuration for web site 'MyWebsite' failed.

Details

> Could not save changes for web site 'MyWebsite'.

More Info

> Please try again. If the problem persists, contact support.

I have tried again multiple times. Suggestions?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We cannot delete a certificate that is in use. Either turn off SSL or upload a replacement certificate before deleting the existing one.

Once we changed the SSL binding, we were able to delete the certificate. **My Website > Configure > SSL Bindings**

[image: We cannot delete a certificate that is in use.]